# Sql query to find select customer that bought in the specific year

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my table in the sql

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (ID char(50), Customer_FName char(50), Customer_Lname char(50));

CREATE TABLE Buying (Customer_ID char(50), Product_ID char(50), Order_Time char(50));

CREATE TABLE Product (ID char(50), Name char(50), Address char(50));
```

I am trying to find all customers who bought a product in 2017 or earlier and list the customer's ID, names

```
select *
from Customer 
INNER JOIN Buying
    Buying.Customer_ID = Customer.ID
where Buying.Order_Time <= '2017-12-31';
```

But I have an error

> ORA-009005 (missing keyword)

Comment: My guess is that you are missing `ON` after Buying and before Buying.Customer_ID

Comment: Unrelated, but: do not use the `char` data type. It has absolutely no advantages whatsoever, but several disadvantages.

Comment: If it don't give error message the problem is your join or your condition, can you post data example and tables definition?

Comment: problem solved for this

Answer (score 2):

```sql
select * from Customer INNER JOIN Buying on Buying.Customer_ID = Customer.ID where extract(year from date Buying.Order_Time) <= 2017;
```

"ON" after Buying is the missing keyword

Comment: This may not return any items bought between `2017-12-31T00:00:01` and `2017-12-31T23:59:59`. You should also not use strings in place of dates as Oracle has to perform an implicit cast to a date and will use the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format in the cast and every user can set their own session parameter values (and the defaults also depends on internationalisation settings) so your query can break without being changed just by different users having different session values.

Comment: you're right - I've focused on syntax flaws, not on the structural flaws - now I suppose it should do the trick.

Comment: The OP wanted "bought a product in 2017 or earlier" so you want `<= 2017` rather than just `= 2017`. Using `EXTRACT` would work if the OP was just inputing a number but the function may prevent Oracle from using an index on the column.

Answer (score 0):

I think are trying to write:

```
select *
from Customer c inner join
     Buying b
     on b.Customer_ID = c.ID
where b.Order_Time < date '2018-01-01';
```

Both `on` and `date` or needed.

However, this will return one row for each purchase before the date.  Use `exists` if you just want one row:

```
select c.*
from Customer c 
where exists (select 1
              from Buying b
              where b.Customer_ID = c.ID and
                    b.Order_Time < date '2018-01-01'
             );
```

Comment: This may not return any items bought between `2017-12-31T00:00:01` and `2017-12-31T23:59:59`.

Comment: @MT0 . . . That is true -- I just used the OP's logic for that portion.  The comparison should be using `<` anyway, to handle dates with and without a time component.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `ON` keyword and there is the additional issue that in Oracle dates always have the components year, month, day, hour, minute and second and (assuming the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter allows a valid cast from a string to a date) then `'2017-12-31'` will be converted to `2017-12-31T00:00:00` and your query will not select values that are between `2017-12-31T00:00:01` and `2017-12-31T23:59:59`.

To fix this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   Customer c
       INNER JOIN Buying b
       ON ( b.Customer_ID = c.ID )
WHERE  b.Order_Time <  DATE '2018-01-01';
```

or

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   Customer c
       INNER JOIN Buying b
       ON ( b.Customer_ID = c.ID )
WHERE  b.Order_Time <  ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( TO_DATE( 2017, 'YYYY' ), 'YY' ), 12 );
```